# What's wrong with my file locking?

Tags: perl

When I do the following, I don't see any lock files (if flock() uses that?).

The problem is that I can run the same script more than once, and it doesn't file the file.

Do I need to install a `Fnctl` package?

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl ':flock'; # Import LOCK_* constants

my $file = 't';
my $can_lockin = 1;

open(my $fh, '>', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' - $!";
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Could not lock '$file' - $!";

print $fh $can_lockin;
sleep 100000000;

#close($fh) or die "Could not write '$file' - $!";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Fcntl ':flock';

$|++; # no buffering

my $file = "status.txt";

open my $fh, '+<', $file or die "can't open $file in update mode: $!\n";
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "couldn't get lock: $!\n";
my $status = <$fh>;
chomp $status;
$status = $status ? '0' : '1';
seek $fh, 0, 0;
print $fh "$status\n";
truncate($fh, tell($fh));

#print "blocking...\n"; sleep 10;

close $fh;
```

This will toggle the contents of the status.txt file back and forth between 1 and 0.
Note that I'm opening the file in "update mode" because I need to read AND write. If you
don't do it this way you can get race conditions. If you uncomment the "sleep" line,
start it running in one window, then run it a second time in anther window, you'll see
that the second run waits at the flock until the first run closes the file (releasing the lock).

Comment: Awesome! That is a very good use case. Can you guess what I will be using it for? =)

Comment: `$|++;` will only affect STDOUT, which you don't even use.

Comment: right - I should have explained that better. The $|++ has nothing to do with the flock stuff. But for the example, I wanted it to print out "blocking" then wait for 10 seconds. If you run it again in a second window during that time, you won't see the second "blocking" appear until the first run exits and releases the lock. But if buffering is on, you won't see the the first "blocking" message until the first run exits.

Comment: A shorter way to `$status = $status ? '0' : '1';` is `$status = !$status;`

Answer (score 4):

[`flock`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/flock.2.html) doesn't use lock files; it is implemented by the operating system.

Bear in mind that UNIX locks are *advisory*, i.e. other programs can still modify the file unless they call `flock` themselves. Also, if a file is locked, the `flock` attempt blocks (waits until the file is unlocked). If you want the program to exit instead of block when trying to acquire a held lock, pass `LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB` to `flock`.

Also note that your open mode is wrong, instead of `>` (truncate the file), you probably want `<+` (open the file for reading and writing) and call [`truncate`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) yourself after you have acquired the lock.

Answer (score 1):

If you add some debug output, you'll see that flock() is blocking and your script is working almost right:

```
...
print "Pre lock\n";
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Could not lock '$file' - $!";
print "Post lock\n";
...
```

You can fix that by bitwise-or'ing LOCK_EX with LOCK_NB.